# Can the variables defined in the post_init method of dataclasses be serialized?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class A:
    x: str
    y: str
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.z = self.x+self.y
```

```
a = A('abc', 'def')
a.z
'abcdef'
from dataclasses import asdict
asdict(a)
{'x': 'abc', 'y': 'def'}
```

As can be seen, `z` is not be serialized. How to serialize it (other than calling `__dict__` on it)?

Comment: Have you tried:  `b = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(a))`?  It appears that `z` is making it through serialization.   It's just not part of the `__str__` function.  Or am I misunderstanding your question.

Comment: My bad, missed a line there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include `z` as a variable when first defining the class but in addition you need to use `field` to omit it from the `__init__` list of parameters.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, asdict

@dataclass
class A:
    x: str
    y: str
    z: str = field(init=False)
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.z = self.x + self.y

a = A("abc", "def")
a.z
>> 'abcdef'

asdict(a)
>> {'x': 'abc', 'y': 'def', 'z': 'abcdef'}
```

You can see more [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing) as shown in the docs.

This is because under the hood to create the dictionary, the `asdict` method fetches the attributes from the `__dataclass_fields__` attribute of the object. Since `z` is not part of those attributes, it will not fetch `z` when converting the object to a dictionary.